# Writing and Reading to/From XML in VC++

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

i have a user login form. i which the user is requested to input name and password and some check boxes and radio buttons. when clicking ok button this data has to be stored in an XML file and be shown next time user logs in. (Much like password remembering of web browsers).

How can be this done. 
All helps appreciated.

thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is some libraries for this, like: [tinyxml](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/)!

you can find more and may be better if you search. look [Here](http://www.ucancode.net/ActiveX_Programming_Article_Com_Tutorial/LOAD-PARSE-SAVE-XML-DOCUMENT-MSXML-LIBRARY-VISUAL-C-ARTICLE.htm) too

Comment: i would like to write my own. so can you explain a bit of how to

Comment: Okay, tinyXML is OpenSource, you can read its code it would be helpful. you want to write a parser yourself? but i think if you want to make a Car you shouldn't invent wheel again!

Comment: string.h has enough function to read XML strings. strstr(), strcmp() and other funtion would be helpful if you want to read a simple XML